# PHP pcntl_fork but still work synchronous

Tags: php

I am new to use pcntl_fork.
Here is my code:

```
<?php
    for($i = 0; $i < 3 ; $i++){
        $pid = pcntl_fork();
        if($pid == -1){
            echo "error\n";
        }elseif($pid == 0){
            echo "child(".getmypid().")\n";
            sleep(3);
            exit();
        }else{
            pcntl_wait($status);
        }
    }
    ?>
```

The 3 process does not echo at the same time.
It seems like the second child waits for the first one and so on.
How can I make the 3 processes work parallely?

Answer (score 0):

My friend solved the question. The child process waiting the previous one is due to the line 11:

```
pcntl_wait($status);
```

It causes the parent wait for the previous process and then start the next process when the first one is end.

Here is the correct code:

```
$pidList = array();
for($i = 0; $i < 3 ; $i++){
    $pid = pcntl_fork();
    if($pid == -1){
        echo "error\n";
    }elseif($pid == 0){
        echo "child(".getmypid().")\n";
        sleep(3);
        exit();
    }else{
        array_push($pidList, $pid);
    }
}
if($pid != 0){
    foreach($pidList as $pid){
        pcntl_waitpid($pid, $status);
    }
}
```